# iOS Push Notification with Rich Content - Can I prevent a notification from being tappable?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have a push notification with rich content.

Can I make it in such way that it is not tappable, i.e., a single tap will not open the application. It must be dragged down to rich content or 3D touched, or deleted from the notification center by swiping.

How should I indicate to the user to drag down (3D touch) in order to reveal rich content on notification?

Comment: To achieve this kind of behaviour you can use silent notification and then show rich content. Silent notification will not visible to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a tap on a push notification will always open the notification in the app, and as far as I know there is no way in public API to override this behavior. It does appear there is a private API to get the behavior you’re looking for, as some iOS-generated (local, not push) notifications appear to do exactly what you’re asking. If you can manage to uncover that, use at your own risk should Apple find out.

Now, as for possible solutions: I would consider implementing code on your app’s delegate to respond appropriately when the notification is opened. For example, send the user to an appropriate location in the app when the app is launched from a notification…perhaps a view controller that shows the same content that would be shown as the rich notification content. I don’t know the exact use case, but the wording implies to me that if the app launches to its main interface, it could be confusing to a user.

It’s impossible for me to tell you how exactly you wish to respond to notifications, so for more on responding appropriately when the app was launched from a push notification, see the following documentation from Apple:

- [Determine Why Your App Was Launched](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/responding_to_the_launch_of_your_app#2922740)
- [`UIApplicationDelegate.application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623032-application)
- [`UIApplicationDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application)
- [`UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/launchoptionskey)
- [`UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/launchoptionskey/1622967-remotenotification)

Hopefully from that you can find a suitable solution. But if that isn’t an option, consider directly telling the user at some point to press firmly (or tap and hold, as many devices do not support 3D Touch) to view the content. You could do this during some onboarding process or, as an absolute last resort, in the notification itself.

Before proceeding down that route, though, understand that not all users know 3D Touch and/or this rich-content functionality even exists — even fewer use it regularly — and if they become confused, they may decide to clear the notification or outright disable your app’s notifications. In general, it’s also a bad idea to “teach” your user unfamiliar ways of using their device. If a user is used to tapping on notifications, as many are, they will most likely tap on your notifications. It can be tough to break that muscle memory.

Comment: Yeah I will navigate user to appropriate screen. It is used to accept friends invitations. I have accept/reject buttons and it seems nice to accept them without opening app or navigating between screens inside app. I also consider adding some unicode icon indicating to press hold, but have no idea what will be suitable. Now just added 3 dots.